# how to keep bandages close to hand dry and clean

Tags: cleaning, personal-care, water

I bet we've all had difficulties with medical gauze or (tensor) bandages being close to the fingers so that each time you wash your hands or do the dishes they get wet. How do you prevent this from happening and how do you dry it when it does get wet? I've got a tensor bandage around the wrist/ thumb of my dominant hand and it interferes with typing and writing.

Answer (score 5):

Get a medical rubber glove and cut the fingers off. It keeps the bandage dry but you still have use of your hand. You can seal the edges with sticky medical bandage if you need to, but only short term.

If your bandage gets wet you can dry it with a hair dryer, or the hand dryer in a public toilet.